# How to uninstall a program (Moneydance 2015)

Tags: uninstall

I have Ubuntu 15.04 and have installed Moneydance 2015.  I want to uninstall it and install Moneydance 2014 instead.  How do I do this?

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you installed it using the .deb package on not the shell script installer, run a package manager and look for it.   If you don't have Synaptic or Aptitude installed, you can use the Ubuntu Software Center; click the INSTALLED button, and use the search box on the right to look for the name.   The package name is "moneydance" so you should also be able to do it from the command line using "sudo apt-get remove moneydance".